# Mirroring messes up my rigging

Tags: modeling, rigging

So I made one leg of my creature and used the mirror modifier to get the other leg. This worked fine, but when I went to rig it, the armature on the original leg controlled both legs, how do I fix this? (And weight painting doesn't help)

Comment: I think you have to apply the *Mirror* modifier, or adjust its order in the stack.